# Photoshop 2019 | Export layers composition to files with respect to arboards + add suffix from the name of layer comps

Tags: automation, photoshop, layer, photoshop-script

Is there any way or script to export layers composition to files with respect to artboards? I need the exported files to be named from artboards and suffix from the name of layer comps?

[image]

Thank you in advance, because I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your script. save it as any name.jsx and move it to your photoshops script Folder**

It'll ask you for folder input and then will save it to appropriate folder with the name condition you said! Have fun :)

```
#target photoshop
var doc=app.activeDocument;
var artbrd=doc.layerSets;//return artboards as array
var lyrcmp=doc.layerComps;//return layercomps as array
var fldr = Folder.selectDialog ("Choose Save Location","");
var lyrcompname;
var artname;
for(var i=0;i<lyrcmp.length;i++){

        var cmpname=lyrcmp[i].name;
        lyrcompname = lyrcmp[i].name;
        var idapplyComp = stringIDToTypeID( "applyComp" );
        var desc353 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref75 = new ActionReference();
        var idcompsClass = stringIDToTypeID( "compsClass" );
        ref75.putName( idcompsClass, cmpname);
        desc353.putReference( idnull, ref75 );
        executeAction( idapplyComp, desc353, DialogModes.NO );
        exportArtboard ();
}

function exportArtboard(){
    for (var z=0;z<artbrd.length;z++){
            artname=artbrd[z].name;
            selectart();

            cutpaste();


            var saveFile = new File(fldr + "/" + artname + "_" + lyrcompname + ".jpg");
            var saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
            saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
            saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
            saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
            saveOptions.quality = 10;
            app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
            app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

        }




}
function cutpaste(){
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

function Action2() {
  // Set
  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), sTID("selection"));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Al  '));
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Copy Merged
  function step2(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    executeAction(sTID('copyMerged'), undefined, dialogMode);
  };

  // Set
  function step3(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), sTID("selection"));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('None'));
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Make
  function step4(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc2.putBoolean(sTID("artboard"), false);
    desc2.putString(sTID("preset"), "Clipboard");
    desc1.putObject(cTID('Nw  '), cTID('Dcmn'), desc2);
    desc1.putInteger(cTID('DocI'), 287);
    executeAction(cTID('Mk  '), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  // Paste
  function step5(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('AntA'), cTID('Annt'), cTID('Anno'));
    desc1.putClass(cTID('As  '), cTID('Pxel'));
    executeAction(cTID('past'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  step1();      // Set
  step2();      // Copy Merged
  step3();      // Set
  step4();      // Make
  step5();      // Paste
};


Action2.main = function () {
  Action2();
};

Action2.main();
}

function selectart(){
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

function select() {
  // Select
  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putName(cTID('Lyr '), artname);
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), false);
    var list1 = new ActionList();
    list1.putInteger(8);
    desc1.putList(cTID('LyrI'), list1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  step1();      // Select
};
select();
}
```

Comment: Big thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, when I run your script I get an error on 96 line of code: **" executeAction(sTID('Mk  '), desc1, dialogMode);"**

Comment: well it works fine on my case. well there is basic requirements : keep only your main PSD open and if there is still issue try creating dummy psd so you can check if your psd have issue since my script running perfectly :) ; in new psd : create 3 artboards and put 2x layers and make 2 or 3 comps and then play script :)

Comment: actually 96th line commands photoshop to create new document from clipboard :) it's same like ctrl+a ; ctrl+c ; and **ctrl+n(96th line)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. What version of photoshop are you working and you work in MacOs or Windows?

Comment: its photoshop 2019 and windows :) don't think that's the issue :)

Comment: It works! I had to change the language in photoshop to English. Big thanks for script! ( ͡o ͜ʖ ͡o)

Comment: that's something even i couldn't guess XD congrats!